# Unable to put text in center of circular buttons

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to design a web page which contains three round buttons with some text in them. But, the problem is I couldn't arrange the text to be at the center of the buttons. The text is horizontally centered. But, it is not vertically centered.
This is the screenshot of the output:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12EXL.png)

Below is the css used:

```
button{
width: 10%;
height: 0;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding-bottom: 10%;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
}
button:hover{
    background-color: #E9D66B;
}
```

Comment: are you allowed to use flexbox?

Comment: please give html code also

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-9cdmx3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by plain HTML CSS code:

```css
button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px gray;
}
```

```html
<button>Hello</button>
<button>Testing</button>
<button>Check</button>
```